# LessCss imports failed with url and anchors

Tags: javascript, css, url, less

I'm trying to import .less files and add some background images in my main less file. The code is (client-side) :

```
@import "child";

.image{
    background-image:url("image.png");
}
```

The Less file is called from the URL:

```
http://localhost/mywebsite#/root.
```

Less compiled the import to :

```
http://localhost/mywebsite#/root//localhost/mywebsite#/root//mywebsite/child.less
```

The background image url to :

```
http://localhost/mywebsite#/root//localhost/mywebsite#/root//mywebsite/image.png
```

Comment: What's with the hash-bang (#) in your URLs?

Comment: I am using javascriptmvc framework so navigation is performed client-side. I am using Chrome or Firefox; problem is the same !

Answer (score 0):

Without a live example, it will be hard to pinpoint the path your code is loading from.

Make sure your loading the files with the correct path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
```

All .less CSS values will load relative to that URL.

You can also try using:

```
.image{
    background-image:url("/image.png");
}
```

If all else fails, you could always use an absolute path to the image

```
.image{
    background-image:url("http://localhost/mywebsite#/root/image.png");
}
```